# Maven Build cannot deploy to Javadoc server: missing SSH known_hosts

Tags: ssh, jenkins

We are using CloudBees Jenkins to run a Maven job and the build is failing when it tries to deploy Javadoc to our private Javadoc server.
This is the error in the logs:

```
The authenticity of host 'javadoc.foo.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3e:69:41:8a:ec:d1:4c:d9:75:ef:7d:71:b7:7d:51:d0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? (yes/no):
The authenticity of host 'javadoc.foo.com' can't be established.
```

I would like to modify the `known_hosts` file on the m1.large and m1.small nodes but i don't know how.

Just thinking out loud, should I have a pre-build step that modifies the `known_hosts` file on the fly? Or perhaps copy a pre-built `known_hosts` file in the `/private` directory?

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I am new to this whole "dynamically created build machines"...

Comment: Please correct me, If I'm wrong, I understand that the connection to your private server is the HTTPS by using self sign certificate. You may consider to inject the server certificate to the Jenkins/Java cacerts.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk:  The connection from the slave machine to the private javadoc server is via scp.  Here is the snippet from the pom.xml:`<distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>site-host</id>
            <url>scp://javadoc.foo.com/var/www/javadoc/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most secure way is to preconfigure known hosts with the values you are expecting - appending the appropriate line for the server you're connecting to.

```
# Run this manually:
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=foo javadoc.foo.com

# Take that file and put it in your private DAV share, and then
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/private/<account>/known_hosts javadoc.foo.com
```

Comment: I can't run it manually.  In cloudbees, the slave/build machines get created on-the-fly, and I don't think I can modify the "base" image of the build machine (I could be wrong on this...).

Comment: doh, you are right. I read your response too quickly. That is essentially the right way to do it.  I ended up saving it the /private/foo/ directory (which all slaves can access), and then when it's time, I use it, just like you mentioned.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ben W's answer is quite good. Alternatively, I would make sure I can login via the console from that machine to wherever so that the ssh client would store the settings by itself.

Comment: I cannot login via the console.  The machine gets created when the job starts and gets destroyed when the job finishes.  So even if I did manage to modify the known_hosts file on the build machine, it will just get blown away after the jenkins job is done. State is not preserved.  Right now, I suspect I have to save a "golden" known_hosts file somewhere, and when the build starts use that "golden" file instead of the one in ~/.ssh/.

Comment: Yep - the home directory is erased on each build - and the "golden file is quite handy as it ensures the trust relationship - better than just saying "YES" to the remote host check. Sort of like SSL without all the pain of CAs.