# maven 3 site-deploy gets stuck in authentication prompt in Jenkins build

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, cloudbees

How do you get rid of this prompt when using site-deploy?
"Are you sure you want to continue connecting?"

I know this question has been asked multiple times ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323040/maven-wagon-scp-is-not-able-to-establish-a-connection), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685988/how-to-avoid-maven-builds-stall-on-ssh-host-authenticity-problem)), but the recommended solutions do not work for me and I will explain why.

Oh, and I posted pretty much the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256021/maven-build-cannot-deploy-to-javadoc-server-missing-ssh-known-hosts)

where the solution is to:

```
# Run this manually:
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=foo javadoc.foo.com

# Take that file and put it in your private DAV share, and then
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/private/<account>/known_hosts javadoc.foo.com
```

Which has been working fine 99% of the time, but using this solution, every once in a while we get the following text over and over again in the logs:

```
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
3d:69:41:8a:ec:d1:4c:d9:75:ef:7d:71:b7:7d:61:d0.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Do you want to delete the old key and insert the new key? (yes/no)
```

So, back to my problem: in a nutshell, the problem is this:
When I run mvn site-deploy, it gets stuck in an infinite loop in Jenkins:

```
The authenticity of host 'javadoc.foo.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3d:69:41:8a:ec:d1:4c:d9:75:ef:7d:71:b7:7d:61:d0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? (yes/no)
The authenticity of host 'javadoc.foo.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3d:69:41:8a:ec:d1:4c:d9:75:ef:7d:71:b7:7d:61:d0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? (yes/no)
```

The machine that this occurs on is a CloudBees machine, so it's not a machine that we own.  In other words, every time we do a build, a brand new machine is provisioned to us.

Our settings.xml has something like:

```
<server>
    <id>javadoc.foo.com</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

If it was a machine that we owned and controlled, we could manually ssh on there and run the ssh command just once so that this is fixed, but like I said, those machines are dynamically provisioned to us.

Since we are using maven 3 and not maven 2, we cannot add the following to our server section of the settings.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <knownHostsProvider implementation="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.NullKnownHostProvider">
        <hostKeyChecking>no</hostKeyChecking>
    </knownHostsProvider>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to either:

1. programmatically answer yes (this is not a free-style Jenkins job; this is Maven project.)
2. an alternative to site-deploy (ant code within the pom.xml?)
3. have site-deploy *fail* if this question does not get answered, so that the Jenkins build doesn't fill gigs of disk space with this question repeated over and over again.
4. tell the site-deploy plugin to set stricthostkeychecking to "no"

I would like to avoid any pre-build steps that could tweak ssh settings; I would prefer to either tweak the settings.xml, pom.xml, or maven options.

Nonetheless, I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a shell pre-build step to create ~/.ssh/config with content :

`StrictHostKeyChecking no`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, even though I was hoping to not have a pre-build step; I was hoping for a pure maven solution (ie modify settings.xml or pom.xml, or set some property to make site-deploy behave nicely), if that makes sense.  Thanks for you suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

You can manage to get it work using this *settings.xml* configuration :

```
<server>
  <id>site</id>
  <username>_your_login_user_</username>
  <privateKey>_path_to_key_identify_file</privateKey>
  <configuration>
    <strictHostKeyChecking>no</strictHostKeyChecking>
    <preferredAuthentications>publickey,password</preferredAuthentications>
    <interactive>false</interactive>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

along with the following *pom.xml* :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.6</version>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency><!-- add support for ssh/scp -->
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
           <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
           <version>2.12</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```

An issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-467 has been addressing the wagon-ssh plugin for the *strictHostKeyChecking* parameter and has been solved in recent versions.

Comment: Perfect; this works for me with `wagon-ssh:3.1.0`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
echo yes | mvn site:deploy
```

Totally fixed this for me despite having tried many other routes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way round this. Using this didnt work: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.NullKnownHostProvider, which seems to be a known issue.

But assuming you're on a unix box of some sort you can do this as a workaround to send yes when prompted if you don't want to change ssh config:

```
echo yes | mvn site:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case that someone would not use `StrictHostKeyChecking no` and also if someone has this problem on Windows I have another solution:

Normaly your `known_hosts` could be found under

> C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.ssh\known_hosts

For the Windows Service Installation of Jenkins you should copy your `known_hosts` to:

> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.ssh\

Or for the case of a Jenkins 64Bit version to:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.ssh\

For Unix/Linux systems use analog paths - copy the known_hosts (or only parts of it) from your account to Jenkins user.